# Date adjusted to next working days after cut-off vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a question, I'm trying to create a macro that has cut off time.

for example:
on the worksheet paper, if the requester logged their request, current date will automatically display, however if the requester logged his/her request after the cut off time the date will be adjusted on the next working days (which is Monday to Friday) let's say my cut off time will be at 4pm

and if the requester logs their request after the cut off, (let us say, **Friday, 4:01 pm**) the date will display the next working day which is Monday.

working days is equivalent to: **MONDAY to FRIDAY**
cut-off will be at **4PM**

is this possible on VBA macro??

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything is possible with a VBA Macro.

So first we need to determine if we are supposed to get the date of today, or the next day.
AM/PM gives me a bit of a headache, so there might be better ways of doing this.
Essentially, if it's past 4PM, we need to go to the next date. 
Then we have to make sure that we don't end up on a weekend, and if we do, figure out when the next monday is.

You could try something like this:

```
Sub aTime()
Dim cTime As Variant, amPm As Variant, wkDay As Long, d As Date, printA As Range, printB As Range
Set printA = Range("A1")                                                'Where to display weekday
Set printB = Range("A2")                                                'Where to display date
d = Date                                                            'Store date
wkDay = Weekday(Now, vbMonday)                                      'Store weekday, assuming monday as start of week
cTime = Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")                    'Store time
amPm = Format(TimeValue(Now), "AM/PM")                              'AM/PM stuff

If cTime > "03:59:59" And cTime < "12:00:00" And amPm = "PM" Then   'Are we too late for today?
    wkDay = wkDay + 1                                               'Yes, go to next weekday
    d = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)                                       'Add one day to date too
End If

If wkDay > 5 Then                                                   'Are we past friday?
    printA.Value = WeekdayName(1)                                   'Yes, set weekday to Monday and print
    printB.Value = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday)               'Find date of next monday and print
Else
    printA.Value = WeekdayName(wkDay)                               'No, Print stored weekday
    printB.Value = d                                                'also print stored date
End If

End Sub
```